# Understanding composition Transformation Matrices for 3D point and composition of Two Matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I have two questions regarding matrix transformation the first one I think I have already solved or at least understood the question and the second one I am not sure.

Given this composite transformation matrix M
$$M =\begin{bmatrix}
4  &0  &0  &2 \\ 
0  &4  &0  &5 \\ 
0  &0  &4  &5 \\  
0  &0  &0  &1 \\  
\end{bmatrix}$$
And the $3D$ point $q = [3, 4, 1]^T$ I am using $p$ as the homogeneous representation of $q$ leading to this $$p =\begin{bmatrix}
 3 \\ 
 4 \\ 
 1  \\ 
 1  \\  
\end{bmatrix}$$ now I might be misremembering this, but the little $^T$ is supposed to showcase that it is column vector.

Calculating $p´ = Mp$ should give me $p´ = [5, 9, 6, 1]^T$

Now what I am trying to understand is if I have composite transformation matrix $M$, and I can assume that $M$ is the composition of two transformations. How would I try to explain what type and in which order the transformations are applied represented by $M$

Comment: Not sure I understand your question, but your computation of Mp does not look correct.

Comment: @blamocur why is that the case is it not `(v1 + t1)`, `(v2 + t2)`, `(v3 + t3)`, when you want to do translation ?

Comment: your matrix M is not a pure translation matrix but includes a scaling by 4 as well, i.e. for this particular matrix it should be (4*v1+t1), (4*v2+t2), (4*v3+t3)

Comment: @blamocur would it then be that the scaling is done first and then the addition or the other way around? and is there an explanation to that as my second question is about that problem where the order matters

Comment: here the scaling is done first. But this all follows from the definition of the multiplication of a matrix and a vector -- look it up. E.g. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_multiplication#Linear_maps